# android get response with whitespaces from url

Tags: android, url, whitespace, httpresponse

i am trying to get the response from a url like it is (with whitespace included ) but the whitespaces are always deleted . this is my code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(link); 
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();       

            String  s = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            String[] ar = s.split(" ");
            Log.e("responsesize" , String.valueOf(ar.length));
            for(int i =0 ; i < ar.length ; ++i)
            {
                Log.e("response" , ar[i]);
            }
```

my response is :  `TRYING2020/1/12014/04/1103` but it should be :

```
TRYING 2020/1/1 2014/04/11 0    3
```

any idea how to do this  ? 
( sry if this is stupid but tried to find a post on it but evthg i c is removing whitespaces from url not keeping from response )

Comment: What You are getting from server ??

Comment: Umm, if you `split()` the string with `" "` (space), then all the spaces will be gone...

Comment: found it ... actually i thought that a tab was a combination of 4 spaces ...  so if i split with spaces i get one array .. but spliting with tabs gives me the response ...  but isnt a tab key =  4 spaces ?

Comment: Code editors often use 4 spaces when you press tab. But tab is actually a different character than space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it . actually i thought that a tab was a combination of 4 spaces ... so if i split with spaces i get one array.But spliting with tabs gives me the response

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
try{

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                URL url = new URL(location);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString();
            }  
    finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
```